# Script JQuery Gallery, pass the CSS class as parameter of a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameters, gallery, image-gallery

Hi I'm new in javascript/programming and I cannot find a reasonable solution for a script who is in charge of giving parameters to each photo gallery. The script is working fine, but as I wrote, I think it can be simplified to no repetition of parameters. There is just one parameter (the class selector) that is changing from each gallery script.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.popup-gallery-wakipo').magnificPopup({ // HERE THE CLASS SELECTOR
        delegate: 'a.gallery_portf',
        type: 'image',
        tLoading: 'Loading image #%curr%...',
        mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
        gallery: {
          enabled: true,
          navigateByImgClick: true,
          preload: [0,1]
        },
        image: {
          tError: '',
          titleSrc: function(item) {
            return item.el.attr('title') + '';
            }
        }
      });


      $('.popup-gallery-instacash').magnificPopup({ // HERE THE CLASS SELECTOR
        delegate: 'a.gallery_portf',
        type: 'image',
        tLoading: 'Loading image #%curr%...',
        mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
        gallery: {
          enabled: true,
          navigateByImgClick: true,
          preload: [0,1]
        },
        image: {
          tError: '',
          titleSrc: function(item) {
            return item.el.attr('title') + '';
          }
        }
      });
```

etc...

So the question is how to modularize this script for just pass that class selector as parameter. Maybe with an Object Construtor/Method, I've tried but I get lost make it work

```
  function Gallery (theclass){

    $('.' + theclass).magnificPopup({
      delegate: 'a.gallery_portf',
      type: 'image',
      tLoading: 'Loading image #%curr%...',
      mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
      gallery: {
        enabled: true,
        navigateByImgClick: true,
        preload: [0,1]
      },
      image: {
        tError: '',
        titleSrc: function(item) {
          return item.el.attr('title') + '';

        }
      }
    });

  }

  var mySecondGallery = new Gallery("popup-gallery-wakipo");

  mySecondGallery ();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function gallery(class) { 
  return $("." + class).magnificentPopup({
  ...
  });
}
var mySecondGallery = gallery("popup-gallery-wakipo");
```

You then have access to the jQuery object.

Comment: sorry, I used like this, and is not working. Here the original JS file: http://pastebin.com/tM002P5U

Comment: Do you need access to the jQuery object, or is it enough if the code only gets executed?

Comment: I'm not sure what JS library is using the gallery :-/, I just know this script make it work. And that assignment you wrote in the las line it doesnt need to be called in some way? Here the HTML of one of the galleries: http://pastebin.com/bqWATSpv find out the class in the line 4

Comment: Why don't you give all elements just the same class and execute the maginficentPopup-code only once?

Comment: Because it's a gallery of galleries, each gallery have is own class